# Event/Observer After password change Automatically logout

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4

I'm looking for a way to hook into the event of customers changing their passwords. So if someone changes the password in the customer front end, I'd like to **logout automatically when user change password in account page**. please help for Automatically logout after change password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook into the event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost` and in the observer, you can write the below code to programatically logout :

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
```

**EDIT**

You need to create a new module.
Let's call it `Company_Module`.
`app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <company_module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </company_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <company_module>
                        <class>company_module/observer</class>
                        <method>logout</method>
                    </company_module>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Observer.php` - the observe class

```
<?php 
class Company_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function logout($observer) {
        if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.7', '<')) {
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: can you please explain where to write your suggested code , i am new to magneto so please help

Comment: Sorry your code is not working for me @Manashvi birla

Comment: Wt error did u get? Share your entire code here

Answer (score 1):

With default Magento, this feature already exists. You can see this in this in the method `Mage_Customer_AccountController::resetPasswordPostAction()` at `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`.

```
public function resetPasswordPostAction()
{
    .....

    try {
        // Empty current reset password token i.e. invalidate it
        $customer->setRpToken(null);
        $customer->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
        $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
        $customer->save();

        $this->_getSession()->unsetData(self::TOKEN_SESSION_NAME);
        $this->_getSession()->unsetData(self::CUSTOMER_ID_SESSION_NAME);

        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot save a new password.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/changeforgotten');
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if everything works good, then Magento will first save new password. Then it will unset current customer session, then customer will be redirected to login page.

So in your case, customer is not logged out means, some customization/rewrite has done to this controller method. You need to find out it and apply same thing that Magento does here in that customized section.

[**Manashvi's answer**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136639/3535) is also good and you can use it without a double thoughts. But in my opinion, the best solution is, apply following changes to the customized section

```
    //invalidate session
    $this->_getSession()->unsetData(self::TOKEN_SESSION_NAME);
    $this->_getSession()->unsetData(self::CUSTOMER_ID_SESSION_NAME);

    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));

    //redirecting to login page
    $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check below event

`customer_save_after`

In above event you can check for password change and logout that particular customer ,

when password is change this event also call so you can try with this event

Hope this will help you.